# What to store in ngrx/store when using angularfire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, redux, angularfire2, ngrx

I am starting to learn angular2 and went all in with ngrx/store (have no previous exp with redux) and firebase app. Now, I can not wrap my head around how to store firebase objects, arrays and stuff in a store. Should I put them as is, for example, put this `FirebaseListObservable` in the store `af.database.list('/items')`? It looks like a good fit (component could just do store.select('items') and template could subscribe on that, and for mutations I can still fire events to the store where I would mutate the list with reducers) but my guess is not because this list can be mutated from outside the store (some other app user who subscribes to the same list). Or should it depend on individual case?

If not, where should I store a reference to that firebase object and what should I put in the store instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [recommended](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable) that only serializable content should be put into the store:

> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store. It's *technically* possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well as interfere with time-travel debugging.

The asynchronous nature of the AngularFire2 observables means you will likely want to integrate them using [@ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects). Effects essentially listen for a particular action, perform some (possibly asynchronous) side effect and then (usually) emit another action.

How you do this will depend upon what it is that you want to do.

For example, if you wish to use `FirebaseListObservable` to perform queries, you might use the typical `READ_ITEMS`, `READ_ITEMS_SUCCESS` and `READ_ITEMS_ERROR` actions and an effect like this:

```ts
@Effect()
readItems$ = this.actions$
  .ofType('READ_ITEMS')
  .switchMap(() => this.af.database
    .list('/items')
    .first()
    .map(items => ({ type: 'READ_ITEMS_SUCCESS', payload: items }))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'READ_ITEMS_ERROR', payload: error.toString() }))
  );
```

However, if you want to listen to realtime changes from a `FirebaseListObservable`, you might do something like this:

```ts
@Effect()
refreshItems$ = this.af.auth
  .switchMap((authState) => authState ?
    this.af.database
      .list('/items')
      .map(items => ({ type: 'REFRESH_ITEMS', payload: items })) :
    Observable.of({ type: 'REFRESH_ITEMS', payload: [] })
  );
```

Note that the second effect does not listen for an action. Instead, it responds to the authentication state and will emit `REFRESH_ITEMS` actions once the user has been authenticated, etc.

In both cases, the effected action would contain a payload of an array of items - which could be processed by a reducer for storage in the store.

Comment: So if I don`t care about time travel debugging and persistence, I could store FirebaseListObservable in the store. If I care about that stuff and want to do it by the book I should use Effects. Basically, it boils down to knowing your exact use case and doing what feels more natural?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, yes. However, time travel debugging and the Redux DevTools (that work with `@ngrx/store` - see [`@ngrx/store-devtools`](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools)) are pretty useful. Personally, I think putting observables into the store is a little weird, as  they don't really contain state, so to speak. It's kinda like putting functions that return state from some other place into the store. But if you want to do it, do it. Also, bear in mind whether or not doing so makes your testing easier or harder.

Comment: my worry is that Firebase objects from angularfire2 are already observables and provide 2-way sync with the database in the cloud which is really neat. and for me to decouple those objects from the store (storing just basic types in the store), seems like double work (me syncing store with firebase object and firebase object syncing with the cloud). And intuitively I worry that I could break the consistency of the list in the store and firebase list. But, this is a good start to try both ways and test.

Comment: This is the exact reason that I ended up landing on this thread. What is the benefit of duplicating state in the front end now, since firebase pretty much keeps you in sync all the time?

Comment: @dreamerkumar I wrote this answer quite some time ago. Refs should not go into the store, but there are other/better approaches. I'll add updating the answer to my TODO list.

Comment: @dreamerkumar Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pg_IGwlPLs&feature=youtu.be&t=18m22s

Comment: Thank you @cartant That is really helpful. The AngularFireRedux can be that clue that will help us not duplicate things between AngularFire and Ngrx https://github.com/davideast/angularfire-redux